# Center UIButton with image next to it

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm trying to create a UIButton where the facebook icon is a part of the centering, however i can't seem to figure out how to make it part of the centering process. So far i've just created a UIButton with the text. I could just create a image next to it, however then it will not be part of the centering.

[image]

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ?  not getting your question properly!

Comment: I wan't to create a UIButton with a icon next to and make sure that both is centered and not just the button with text

Comment: @Lion the question is clear as day. The image and text should be "grouped" as one object and centered.

Comment: @KæmpeKlunker : i want to know that questioner uses image separate from button or not so that can write proper answer...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily set image and title both for your button for different control state like `normal,selected or highlighted etc`.

So, set your image and title to your button from storyboard or programmatically there is no need to take separate `imageview` for image.

You can set `edge insets` for `title` and `image` both from interface builder or programmatically. you can manage `top or bottom` edge insets for title and image of button to manage it's vertical appearance!

check screen shot below,

[image]

**Update :** (as asked in comment)

For example,

[image]

this is the setup for my back button with image!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, i add a uibutton to my interface builder, however what about the image?

Comment: select that button in interface builder then from `attribute inspector` set it's `image` !! (your fb icon)

Answer (score 0):

Provide button title and image for normal state. Then just change the left inset for image as per image

[image]